# I am trying to get the rectangles in two different classes to collide but in pygame but it doesn't work no matter what I do

Tags: python, class, pygame

My code works for the most part, but I don't know how to access the rectangles of the tower and enemy classes outside of these classes. Then I would like to use collisions as a way of deleting the enemy class, later I will change it to a health bar system. It is supposed to be a tower defense game. I have been trying to figure out how to do the collision for some time. Could anyone help me such that I can finally move on to a level system and health bars and login system. Any tips will be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

```py
def wave(quantity, size, distance):
    global saiba
    hh = True
    for i in range(quantity):
        saiba = Enemy(800 + (distance + size)*i, 100- size/2, size, size)
        MainWindow.enemy.append(saiba)

def button_tower(x, y, width, height, mouse, click, image, action = None):
    if x+width > mouse[0] > x and y+height > mouse[1] > y:
        if click[0] == 1 and action != None:
            MainWindow.action_box = action

def tower(width=30, height=30):
    global goku
    goku = Tower(MainWindow.mouse[0], MainWindow.mouse[1], width, height)
    MainWindow.tower.append(goku)

class Main:


    def __init__(self, width = WIDTH+100, height = HEIGHT + 100):
        pygame.display.set_caption('DBZ Tower Defense')
        self.startwave = False
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.Gamewindow = pygame.display.set_mode((self.width, self.height))

    def wave(self):
        self.startwave = True

    def Intro(self):
        while True:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    sys.exit()

            self.Gamewindow.fill(BLACK)
            largeText = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 30)
            TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects("simple tower defense game", largeText)
            TextRect = (100, 100)
            self.Gamewindow.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)


            button_text("New game", 100, 200, 400, 50, GREEN, LGREEN, MainWindow.MainLoop)
            button_text("Continue", 100, 300, 400, 50, RED, LRED)
            button_text("Exit", 100, 400, 400, 50, BLUE, LBLUE, quit)
            pygame.display.update()

    def MainLoop(self):
        self.enemy = []
        self.tower = []

        self.action_box = None
        while True:
            Mainclock.tick(60)

            self.mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            self.click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    sys.exit()
                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == ord('t'):
                        tower()
            
            if self.startwave == True and len(self.enemy)==0:
                wave(10, 20, 8)
                self.startwave = False
        
        
        
            **tt = self.enemy.rect.colliderect(self.tower.rect)
            if tt:
            del self.enemy[index]**
        
        

            for index,ene in enumerate(self.enemy):
            
                ene.update()
                ene.move()
                if ene.rect.left <= 0:
                    del self.enemy[index]
        
        

            self.Gamewindow.fill(CYAN)
            self.Gamewindow.blit(light_image_map1, background_rectangle)
            button_tower(800, 0, 50, 50, self.mouse, self.click, fantower_image, tower)

            if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0] == 1 and self.action_box != None:
                rectangle30 = pygame.Rect(self.mouse[0]-15, self.mouse[1]-15, 30, 30)
                self.Gamewindow.blit(action_box_image, rectangle30)
            elif self.action_box != None:
                self.action_box()
                self.action_box = None
            for object_enemy in self.enemy:
                self.Gamewindow.blit(fantower_image, object_enemy.rect)
            for object_tower in self.tower:
                self.Gamewindow.blit(object_tower.image, object_tower.rect)

            button_text("Start next wave", 0, 600, WIDTH, 100, PURPLE, LPURPLE, MainWindow.wave)
            pygame.display.update()


class Enemy:
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, width, height)
        self.dir = 4
        self.movement = [(810, 100, 2), (810, 300, 4), (575, 300, 8), (575, 230, 4), (385, 230, 2), (385, 300, 4), (276, 300, 2), (276, 392, 4), (70, 392, 8), (70, 300, 4)]

   def move(self): 
       if self.dir == 8:
           self.rect.centery -= 1
        if self.dir == 4:
           self.rect.centerx -= 1
       if self.dir == 6:
           self.rect.centerx += 1
       if self.dir == 2:
           self.rect.centery += 1

    def update(self):
        for pos in self.movement:
             if self.rect.center == (pos[0], pos[1]):
                self.dir = pos[2]

    def color(self, colorid):
        return COLORS[colorid]




class Tower:
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x-15, y-15, width, height)
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(tower1, (50, 50))

        def colliderec(self):
            if self.rect.collidedict(self.rect):
                print("true")
```

Comment: So what exactly is wrong?

Comment: The code doesn't work i do not know how to reference the rectangles from both classes

Comment: But each class has its own `self.rect` attribute. It looks like you were trying to write a method to check for a collision, but I'm not sure which way you are going.

Comment: ye i took a break of about 4 months and i forgot what i was doing, if i were going to create a method that would check for collisions which class would i do it in and what would it look like

Comment: Whatever you want it to look like. In general you need to compare all the towers with all the enemies, so there are two levels of things here: Arranging to do the comparisons and actually doing them. I hesitate to provide any code because it would look like I'm doing your work for you.

Comment: so how would I reference both of them in one class because when i tried to do that it just said not defined

Comment: You need to pass one to the other: `tt = tower.collderec(enemy)` But first I would say that you need to be clear whether your `self.tower` and `self.enemy` are lists or single instances.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple of issues, but let's start with the base question:

> I don't know how to access the rectangles of the tower and enemy classes outside of the class

One of the important ideas of Objects is that you generally *don't* directly-access the internal items.  It's more that you "hide" the internal operation, such that a set of similar objects can present a consistent *interface* to the outside code.  For example the `testCollision( a_rect )` function of a *circular* object might be different to that of a *rectangular* one, but the user of the functions only needs to know that you pass a rect, and get a boolean returned.  The secrets of how the collision works is hidden.

Thinking about this, we can modify the `Tower` and `Enemy` objects the same:

```
class Enemy:
    # ...
    def collidesWith( self, other_rect ):
        """ Return true, if other_rect overlaps my rect """
        result = self.rect.colliderect( other_rect )

    def get_rect( self ):
        """ Get a copy of the rect, in PyGame style """
        return self.rect.copy()
```

We try not to access the internals of the object directly.  The idea is to pass what's needed into member functions, and have it work on itself.

> [...] use collisions as a way of deleting the enemy class

You already have a list of `Tower` and a list of `Enemy`, assuming that a collision of the two, results in the death of the `Enemy`.  But currently there is no support for this, so lets add it:

```
class Enemy:
    def __init__( self ):
        # etc...
        self.dead = False   # not dead = alive

    # Is this enemy alive
    def die( self, action=True ):
        self.dead = action

    def isDead( self ):
        return self.dead
```

And now use it:

```
for tower in self.tower:
    tower_rect = tower.get_rect()
    for enemy in self.enemy:
        if ( enemy.collidesWith( tower_rect ) ):
            # Make enemy dead
            enemy.die()
```

This marks some elements of the `self.enemy` list as "dead".  Then it's a simple loop to remove them:

```
for i in range( len( self.enemy ) - 1, -1, -1):   # note: loop backwards
    if ( self.enemy[i].isDead() ):
        del( self.enemy[i] )
```

Notice that we loop backwards.  This is so we can delete items from the list while iterating.  If the code uses an increasing iteration, it will skip items whenever something is deleted (and then crash at the end).

Comment: Thank you very much you are a very very big help.

Comment: i keep getting an error that self.enemy and self.tower are not defined

Comment: @omzy54 The code-change needs to be made in the scope of class `Main`, which defines those

Comment: i get the error local variable tower referenced before assignment, how would i fix this

Comment: @omzy54 - Please make a new question for this.  It's best to include the relevant code, and the whole exact text of the error message.  Explain what it is you don't understand about the error.